# Excel VBA - XML's InsertBefore command throws Run-Time error 5

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I have to move `PrescriberOrderNumber` to above `Sent time` within the header of the xml document.  In the below code, when I can create the node it throws it at the bottom of the list. When attempting to use `InsertBefore`, it throws a Runtime 5 error.

XML:

```
<Message xmlns="http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/SCRIPT" version="010" release="006">
    <Header>
        <To Qualifier="D">6199568422001</To>
        <From Qualifier="P">0001060</From>
        <MessageID>992a39320ba04a53b1e44094389c063a</MessageID>
        <SentTime>2013-07-03T14:24:47.005371Z</SentTime>
        <PrescriberOrderNumber>ZSUR10009D</PrescriberOrderNumber>
    </Header>
```

VBA script:

```
    Case "SentTime"
        Dim objRoot As IXMLDOMNode
        Dim objMemberElem As IXMLDOMNode

        Set objRoot = oXMLDoc3.DocumentElement

        'Create 1 Child Element
        Set objMemberElem = oXMLDoc3.createElement("RelatesToMessageID")
        objMemberElem.Text = n.Text

        Set node = objRoot.SelectSingleNode("*/SentTime")
        objRoot.ChildNodes.Item(0).appendChild objMemberElem

        objRoot.InsertBefore objMemberElem, node
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Check that the `selectSingleNode` method is actually returning something. I think you may have a default namespace issue which is quite common with MSXML2 but I would need to see the code which declares and creates `oXMLDoc3` to be certain

Answer (score 0):

For the problem detailed in the question - "I have to move `PrescriberOrderNumber` to above `Sent time` within the header of the xml document" - this should work:

```
Dim objHeader As IXMLDOMNode
Dim objPrescriberOrderNumber As IXMLDOMNode
Dim objSentTime As IXMLDOMNode

Set objHeader = oXMLDoc3.selectSingleNode("Message/Header")    
Set objPrescriberOrderNumber = objHeader.selectSingleNode("PrescriberOrderNumber")
Set objSentTime = objHeader.selectSingleNode("SentTime")
objHeader.insertBefore objPrescriberOrderNumber, objSentTime
```

In your original code you called `insertBefore` on `objRoot` but you need to call `insertBefore` on the parent node of the node before which you are inserting the new node. As you were inserting before `node` whose parent was `Header`, you need to call `insertBefore` on `Header` and not on `Message`

If you also need to create a `RelatesToMessageID` child node (as shown in the VBA code in the question) then to insert that before `SentTime` would require this additional code:

```
Dim objMemberElem As IXMLDOMNode
Set objMemberElem = oXMLDoc3.createNode(NODE_ELEMENT, "RelatesToMessageID", oXMLDoc3.documentElement.namespaceURI)
objMemberElem.Text = n.Text

objHeader.insertBefore objMemberElem, objSentTime
```

Note the change from `createElement` in the original code to `createNode` here - this is needed to prevent the added element from being in a different namespace to the rest of the document

Also, using `DOMDocument` is a synonym for `DOMDocument30` - this is the older type of DOM document from MSXML2 v3.0. The current MSXML2 v6.0 DOM document would be declared as `DOMDocument60`. The newer version should be preferred whenever possible - see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2006/10/23/using-the-right-version-of-msxml-in-internet-explorer.aspx)

Using `DOMDocument60` would require some changes to the code as presented. Specifically, the calls to `selectSingleNode` would change to using XPath instead of XSL Patterns. Whilst, in this case, the syntax is the same for the actual node selection, the MSXML2 implementation of XPath requires additional work for default namespaces. You would have to declare a prefix for the default namespace and then use that prefix in the calls to `selectSingleNode` (see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288147) for details) like this:

```
Dim oXMLDoc3 As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Set oXMLDoc3 = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
oXMLDoc3.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:r='http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/SCRIPT'"

Set objHeader = oXMLDoc3.selectSingleNode("r:Message/r:Header")
```